# Products Model testing Using Rspec and capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, capybara

Product.rb

```
 class Product < ApplicationRecord
 validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: true

end
```

Product_spec.rb

```
require 'rails_helper'
require 'capybara/rspec'

RSpec.feature "Create Product", :type => :feature do

scenario "User creates a duplicate product" do
    visit "/products/new"

    fill_in "Name", :with => "My Widget"
    click_button "Create"
    #expect(page).to have_content("Name has already been taken")
    #expect(flash[:notice]).to have_content("Name has already been taken")

     expect(flash[:alert]).to match(/Name has already been taken/)
  end

  scenario "User creates a invalid product" do
     visit "/products/new"

     fill_in "Name", :with => ""
     click_button "Create"

     expect(flash[:alert]).to have_text("Name can't be blank.")
  end

 end
```

Error Displayed : 
[image: Error]

How do I catch the error messages that are raised in Flash ? I tried everything like to have_content , to contain etc

Answer (score 2):

You don't have access to the `flash` object in the tests, you only have access to what's shown on the page.  As such you should be doing

```
expect(page).to have_content("Name has already been taken")
```

or if you want to check that the text is appearing in the correct place in the page and assuming it's appearing inside an element with an id of 'flash' you could do

```
expect(find('#flash')).to have_content("Name has already been taken")
```

You don't actually show in your tests where another Product has been created that would collide with the one you are now creating, could that be why your tests are failing?

As an aside, assuming the `RSpec.feature` alias you're using is the one provided by Capybara it already sets the `type: :feature` metadata when it's used so there is no need for you to also specify it.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I catch the error messages that are raised in Flash?

The flash is simply a hash which is stored in the session storage. Doing `flash.alert('Oh no')` does not raise an exception and cannot be caught.

**You're just testing it wrong**

A feature spec is an end to end spec where you actually make a http request to the rails server and then feed the response into a web browser simulator.

This means that your spec and the rails code which responds to the requests run in completely different processes. So you cannot access the flash hash. This is unlike controller tests which fake the whole request faze and allow you to pry into the rails app.

Instead what you test in a feature spec is the application from the users point of view.

```
require 'rails_helper'
require 'capybara/rspec'

RSpec.feature "Product creation" do

  after(:each) do
    Product.destroy_all
  end

  scenario "when a user creates a duplicate product" do
    product = Product.create(name: "My Widget")
    visit "/products/new"
    fill_in "Name", with: product.name
    click_button "Create"
    expect(page).to have_content("Name has already been taken")
  end

  scenario "when a user creates a product without a name" do
     visit "/products/new"
     fill_in "Name", with: ""
     click_button "Create"
     expect(page).to have_content("Name can't be blank.")
  end
end
```

Comment: As Tom Walpole hinted the reason your specs are failing could be that your specs are not actually cleaning up after themselves. You might want to look into the database_cleaner gem and using factories instead of fixtures.